# Working with Large operations that kill the kernel

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, bigdata

I have written the following code to load data from a postgres data base and do some operations on it. There are about 1million rows and the kernel keeps dying. When i limit the data size to about 10k, it works.

```
import psycopg2
import sys, os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import creds as creds
import pandas.io.sql as psql


## ****** LOAD PSQL DATABASE ***** ##
# Sets up a connection to the postgres server.
conn_string = "host="+ creds.PGHOST +" port="+ "5432" +" dbname="+ creds.PGDATABASE +" user=" + creds.PGUSER \
+" password="+ creds.PGPASSWORD
conn=psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
print("Connected!")

# Create a cursor object
cursor = conn.cursor()


sql_command = "SELECT * FROM {};".format(str("events"))
print (sql_command)

# Load the data
data = pd.read_sql(sql_command, conn)

# taking a subet of the data until algorithm is perfected. 
# seed = np.random.seed(42)

# n = data.shape[0]
# ix = np.random.choice(n,10000)
# df_tmp = data.iloc[ix]

# Taking the source and destination and combining it into a list in another column 
# df_tmp['accounts'] = df_tmp.apply(lambda x: [x['source'], x['destination']], axis=1)
data['accounts'] = data.apply(lambda x: (x['source'], x['destination']), axis=1)
data['accounts_acc'] = data['accounts'].cumsum().apply(set)
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this that doesnt keep failing?

Comment: how many columns are you bringing back? because 1M Rows is fine. Also where is it failing? Is it on the Postgres side?

Comment: I guess the problem is with the "apply" method because it consumes a lot of memory. Try to replace it.

Comment: It’s failing on the pandas side. I doesn’t have that many columns just 6 and I can trim it down. The apply method is taking two tables and combines the values into a tuple and storing it in another column

Comment: @J.K any ideas on what to change it with?

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is with the "apply" method because it consumes a lot of memory.

Try to replace it with :

```
data['accounts'] = [(t.source, t.destination) for t in data.itertuples()]
```

Let's try to test a **Dataframe with 600,000 rows and 4 columns**

**Memory performance** :

```
%memit df['accounts1'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['col1'], x['col2']), axis=1)
```

peak memory: 506.66 MiB, **increment: 114.62 MiB**

```
%memit run_loop()
```

peak memory: 475.82 MiB, **increment: 82.15 MiB**

```
%memit df['accounts2'] = [(t.col1, t.col2) for t in df.itertuples()]
```

peak memory: 430.07 MiB, **increment: 38.02 MiB**

```
def run_loop():
    new_col = []
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        result = str(row.col1)+","+str(row.col2)
        new_col.append(result)
```

**Time performance**:

```
%timeit df['accounts1'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['col1'], x['col2']), axis=1)
```

9.93 s ± 345 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
%timeit df['accounts2'] = [(t.col1, t.col2) for t in df.itertuples()]
```

598 ms ± 16.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: I think apply grown `O(n^2)` and bigger sets blow it up on this laptop. Thanks for the  answer and in-depth analysis